# $.Ajax in MVC4 - loading a file in the url:

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a straight forward function in a separate script file using ASP.NET web forms that works fine:

```
function loadJSON() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'jsondata/names.json', 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           names = data;
        });
        myFunction(names);
```

I've moved over to MVC4 but this method doesn't work as it doesn't recognise the

```
url: 'jsondata/names.json'
```

to access the file and returns data undefined - if I hard code the data as an array then it's fine.

Am I getting the syntax wrong for the file path to load or am I needing to use **success:** to call a function in a controller as I have seen some examples do albeit not by loading a file ?

Comment: Is it something simple, like your script moved to a new location, relative to the `jsondata/names.json` ?

Comment: I don't think so I've placed it in the root, the root of the active folder and in a dedicated folder and it's the same. I think that MVC doesn't utilise the url option the same way as a web form project. I think I need to retrieve the file and its data using a controller and then use the Ajax.Get or getJson from the deserialized result.

Answer (score 0):

instead of hard coding the url use url.action

```
url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
```

Comment: I'm currently not using a controller - $.ajax gets/loads the file directly in web forms from the script or in the head - if I use a contoller I'd need a method to load the file. Does $.ajax not return a file content directly in MVC4 ?

Comment: .ajax will return whatever you need it to return but it returns it through the data attribute (data: { id: 'id' }.  you can pass data through the url but just as query strings